# Bash script to close multiple remote branches from text-file

Tags: bash, git

**Background**

I need to close multiple Git branches (hundreds) that have been left open on a remote repository.

I wanted to sort them by last-commit and put them in a text-file so others could confirm they were no longer needed.

I found a method that allowed me to dump them in a way that I could distribute (and open in Excel to sort by date)

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate:short) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n >> branches.txt
```

And then I need to read the updated text-file back in and delete the remote branches:

```
#!/bin/bash

#prefix of the branches if they are all remote
prefix="refs/remotes/origin/"
prefix1="refs/remotes/"

# path to branches, compiled with:
# git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate:short) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n >> branches.txt

# read through entire input
input="branches.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  # echo "$line"]
  IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
  # search the array for the prefix of the branch
  for index in "${!array[@]}"
  do

    if [[ ${array[$index]} == *"refs/remotes/origin"* ]]; then
      #echo -e " \e[34m ${array[$index]} \e[39m Last commit: \e[34m" ${array[0]} ${array[1]} ${array[2]} ${array[3]} ${array[4]} 
      # echo ${array[$index]#"$prefix"}

      #remove the prefix if they are not pulled locally
      branch=${array[$index]#"$prefix"}

      echo $(git push origin --delete $branch)
    fi
  done
done < "$input"
```

**Issue**

However, keep getting an error that the `refspec` does not exist:

> fatal: invalid refspec ':PracticeBranch?'

I don't have the `'` or `?` in the name of the `branch` variable - so this is probably my ignorance of using `echo` with `bash but I don't know where it is coming from.

A command like:

```
git push origin --delete PracticeBranch
```

When calling directly from the shell?